# Testing tetrahedron-triangle intersection

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I want to determine whether a given triangle intersects a tetrahedron. I do not want to compute the solution polygon(if it exists) itself. Is there any library/package/published *practical* algorithm which can be used to solve this problem *directly*(unlike my attempt below)?

I think as a last resort I will have to use standard polygon-polygon intersection algorithm implementations to solve this problem *indirectly*.

**My attempt on this problem:**
I thought of breaking it into the problem of polygon-polygon intersection. So for each triangular face(say `T1`) of the tetrahedron and the given triangle `T2`, I thought of doing the following:

1. Compute intersection(a line) between planes corresponding to each triangle, say `L1`.
2. For each triangle:

   1. For each edge of the triangle say `L2`, compute point of intersection `P` between `L1` and `L2`.
   2. Test(maybe using parametric form) of `L2`, if the point lies on the edge `L2`.

If for both triangles `T1` and `T2`, there exists *at least one* edge on which the intersection point `P` lies, then it implies that the triangles(and hence the given tetrahedron and the triangle `T2`) *do* intersect.

Comment: Due to the convexity of the geometric entities, you can cast the problem as a linear program in 7 positive unknowns, withd equations expressing that the admissible points belong to the inside of the tetrahedron and the triangle. Solve by the simplex algorithm.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Would you please elaborate on what those 7 unknowns will be?

Comment: The weights of the convex combinations of vertices (3 for triangle, 4 for tetrahedron). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination

Comment: @YvesDaoust So as I understand your approach, this tetrahedron-triangle intersection problem can be translated into a linear _feasibility problem_, where the constraint equation can be of form: alpha*P_{tet}=beta*P_{tri}, where alpha,beta are weight vectors for points of tetrahedron and triangle respectively, P_{tet} and P_{tri} are coordinate vectors of tetrahedron and triangle respectively.

Comment: That's it. There is an intersection iff the linear problem is feasible. Algebraically speaking, the problem is solved by evaluating the signs of a number of 4x4 determinants ("on which side of this plane am I ?" = "signed volume of simplexes") and discussing the outcomes. This is the same kind of machinery as used in my answer (possibly complemented by bounding box tests), where part of the work takes place in 2D space, using 3x3 determinants.

Answer (score 1):

Create an orthonormal frame based on the triangle (origin at some vertex, axis X using the direction of some side, axis Y and Z using the direction of another side and Gram-Schmidt formulas).

Transform the coordinates of the 3 + 4 vertices to the new frame.

If all Z of the 4 tetrahedron vertices are of the same sign, there is no intersection. Otherwise, find the 3 or 4 intersection point of the edges into XY, by linear interpolation on Z.

Now you need to check for intersections between a triangle and a triangle or (convex) quadrilateral, in 2D. You can solve that by means of a standard [clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm), made simple by convexity of the polygons.

As an easy optimization, note that it is useless to compute the Z of the triangle vertices (=0), and the XY of the tetrahedron vertices before you know that there is a possible intersection.

You can also speedup the polygon intersection process by first using a bounding box test.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution. I depicted what I understand to be a counterexample in 2D, where there is no intersection, but your approach would report an intersection. https://imgur.com/ZXIUcYI  The triangle is a line segment, and the tetrahedron is a triangle.

Comment: @Gus: you misunderstood my solution.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could explain my misunderstanding, or clarify your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a function in CGAL library [`CGAL::do_intersect(Type1< Kernel > obj1,Type2< Kernel > obj2 )`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__do__intersect__linear__grp.html#ga9514a218a097ac392d21775368d3dd0d) for computing intersection between two geometric objects. It permits `Type1` and `Type2` to be [`Triangle_3<Kernel>`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Triangle__3.html) and [`Tetrahedron_3<Kernel>`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Tetrahedron__3.html) respectively.